# How to avoid different category extension define the same methods

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, polymorphism, categories

Objective-c class can be extended by categories.
But with multi category extensions on a same class by over define a same method, the result is not defined -- As following case:

```
@implementation someClass (category1)

- (void)foo {}

@end

@implementation someClass (category2)

- (void)foo {}

@end
```

In that case, compiler even won't show any warning message. In some big project and with different people for maintenance, this kind of case is quite difficult to be addressed.

So my question is: is there any sophisticated pattern or resolution for avoiding this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For big projects, a good practice is to also add a prefix to your method names like :

```
- (void)nd_foo;
- (void)sp_foo;
```

Comment: I recommend using a capitalised prefix, as you would for class names.  Selectors are case sensitive, so that'll help distinguish namespacing prefixes from prefixes that are merely words.  e.g. "ATPosition" instead of "atPosition".  The underscore does serve a similar purpose, though some code bases use underscores in method names regularly, so it can be ambiguous.

Comment: It makes sense, but for the implementations I've seen, devs usually use small chars for methods prefixing.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Seems this is the best way I've heard until now.